# SQL Server Always Encrypted w/ Secure Enclave - Key Management Strategy

Tags: sql-server, amazon-kms, always-encrypted, enclave

I am looking into ways to build a data warehouse that would house confidential data for 1+ clients. The requirement is that our organization can *never* obtain access to the decrypted data. There would be a web application clients utilize to write data and query data (basic select statements including ranges).

I've been learning about SQL Server Always Encrypted w/ Secure Enclaves (and Azure SQL Always Encrypted w/ Secure Enclaves) and am wondering about key management strategies.

Based on what I've read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-enclaves?view=sql-server-ver16 and even here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/modernizing-with-aws/sql-server-always-encrypted-with-secure-enclaves/ , it seems like at the end of the day, someone in an organization utilizing this, is going to maintain access of the actual keys that could be used to decrypt the data.

Microsoft suggests role separation such that a DBA may have access to the database, but not access to the keys used for encryption and a Security Admin has access to the keys but not the actual database.

But, hypothetically, if the DBA and Security Admin wanted to be malicious *together*, they could technically obtain access to the data together. Are there strategies that can be employed to help mitigate this potential risk?

I'm wondering if the key management could be placed onto the client(s) instead of one of our own Security Admins - that way, technically, it would be completely impossible for our organization to ever have access to the data in a decrypted form. This would mean that for each client, there would be a column master key that they would store/manage and pass to us (encrypted). We'd use this to programmatically retrieve the column encryption key(s) relevant to their querying.

I've never worked around architectures involving confidential computing and am curious if the direction I am headed seems reasonable and/or if folks have any thoughts, advice, or could point me to any documentation involving key management strategies where clients house their own keys to access their data hosted by some other service.

Comment: Would key escrow be possible to consider and/or applicable?

Comment: I’m not sure it is applicable but thanks for suggesting. I started looking at customer managed keys but not sure if they’re applicable to azure always encrypted or something equivalent

Comment: I think a Key Vault will work in this case.

Comment: I haven’t seen a specific way to employ customer managed keys via key vault with sql server always encrypted , does anyone know if this is a thing and could you point me in the right direction? @WandererAboveTheSea

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-tutorial-getting-started?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ssms This might help.